# How to create A4 size PDF and template in Visualforce or Salesforce?

Tags: visualforce, renderas

I am creating a PDF in email template in Visualforce and the PDF's layout is not properly showing. How should I create a layout using Visualforce to get A4 size PDF in attachment of email?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PDF renderer supports (some) CSS. You can modify the page size just by adding a CSS style inline in your page, as you would in ordinary HTML destined for page-based layout:

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        @page { 
            size: a4;
        }   
    </style>
</head>
```

This generates an A4-sized PDF.